# How to print Exchange server name to screen for a given username

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script that takes username and find its mailbox server.

this is what I tried:

```
$mailboxDetails = get-mailbox -id MyUser

write-host $mailboxDetails
```

*MyUser is my username in AD

this code prints me my First name + Last name.

but if I run in powershell only:

```
get-mailbox -id MyUser
```

I received this:

```
Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
First Last             First.Last               blabla01             unlimited
```

And I want to know how to:
1) print to the screen **only** the server name (in this case "blabla01"), how can I get it to a parameter?

2) how to print the whole table in a pop-up box (not in power shell console, with wshell) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get-mailbox myuser | select servername
```

or

```
$mailboxdetails = get-mailbox myuser | select servername
write-host $mailboxdetails
```